# AES256 encrypted data unable to be copied and paste

Tags: encryption, openssl, aes

I am using OpenSSL to encrypt my data. Assuming I have 3 rows of data(for simplicty)
0123456789
987654321
121212121

After encrypting, I get

```
Salted__èøm¬è!^¬ü
?‘¡ñ1•yÈ}, .◊¬ó≤|Úx$mø©
```

However, when I copy using my Mac's CMD+ C, then I paste in another file to be decrpyted, i get this error
bad decrypt

```
0076160502000000:error:1C80006B:Provider routines:ossl_cipher_generic_block_final:wrong final block length:providers/implementations/ciphers/ciphercommon.c:429:
```

However if I did not copy and paste the encrpyted data, it can be decrypted properly. I believe is due to the spacings changed.. Is it that we cannot copy the data to another file to be decrpyted and MUST use the exact file that was encrpyted?

Comment: What you have printed is a ciphertext decoded with a charset encoding, e.g. UTF-8, which usually corrupts the data. The correct way is to print the Base64 encoded ciphertext. This can then be copied and pasted into the target system, where it can be decrypted after Base64 decoding. In this context, also note the -a /-base64/-A options of [openssl enc](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.1.1/man1/enc.html).

Comment: Yes, welcome to the world of unprintable characters. Not every byte or byte combination represents a printable character (and otherwise font support or Unicode normalization may be problematic).